# Pass data from UITableViewCell to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a class that extend from `UITableViewCell` that has a global variable. I want to access that variable (`selectedMaterialId`) in another ViewController.
PrepareForSegue is just works for ViewController. How can i do that?

My Cell Class is:

```
class MaterialsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var materialCodeLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var materialDescLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var greenBtnOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var redBtnOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yellowBtnOutlet: UIButton!

public var selectedMaterialId = 0
@IBAction func redBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    selectedMaterialId = sender.tag

    }
}
```

I want to access `selectedMaterialId` in another VC

Comment: In your post `selectedMaterialId ` is not a global var.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to use selectedMaterialId variable from your custom tableviewcell(MaterialsTableViewCell). Inshort, you want to pass data from one class to another. You can make use of delegates concept to pass the value

Comment: Can you please explain more? Or just share a link?

Comment: This link will help you out in understanding delegates and protocols and how you can use them to pass data between classes. [https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is push a view controller after having triggered a segue from a table view cell, just prepare the segue from the controller owning the tableview like below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    if 
        let senderCell = sender as? MaterialsTableViewCell,
        let yourController = segue.destination as? YourControllerClass {

        yourController.selectedMaterialId = senderCell.selectedMaterialId

    }



}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can call this function in Tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    variables.name = variables.nameArray[indexPath.row]

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nameofcontroller")
    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[Show storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzn5g.png), Into new ViewController

you can create an public variable you can use overall.

```
class variables
{
    static var name: String = ""
}
```

So in the new controller call this here:

```
print("\(variables.name)")
```